# Audio track switching impossible with MPL 0.7.0 and smoothstream protocol

Tags: chromecast, smooth-streaming

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. On mediaManager loadData, stream info (audio) is sent to sender.
2. Selected audio track index is sent back to receiver.
3. Receiver disables the existing audio stream and enables the new selected     audio stream and reloads the player.

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Expected Output: Audion stream should be enabled on the protocol, and no duplicate of stream info should be present.

Current output: No new audio stream is enabled and duplicate stream info is present,and if you change the audio stream again on client and send it to receiver, now the stream info count is tripled.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
Mac, MPL 0.7.0
Smooth streaming playready DRM.

Please provide any additional information below.

Also something very strange: My asset has swedish audio lang as default, but while fetching the audio stream info from smoothstreaming protocol, the first lang is selected by default (in this case it is finish), no matter what. Even if one tries to modify the protocol manually, MPL throws an exception as "Uncaught exception: cannot call method Ra of null"

And it always reamins the first lang of the protocol audio stream , no matter how many times the player is reloaded.

P.S. - There is no API document for smoothstream protocol, the one which is present in API refrences, slapped me with 404 error.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/player.StreamingProtocol

Comment: Issues related to MPL need to be files at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list, please open a ticket there. You can also take a look there to see if that issue has already been raised or not.

Comment: thanks for the update. I have already done but no reply in 12 hours, thought of posting it here. There has been similar issues on google cast issue forum.

Comment: Hi, my asset has 2 audio streams... but how can I start the custom receiver with the second stream? Upon `onMetadataLoaded` I enable the second audio stream, disable first audio stream and call `player.reload()`, however it doesn't work... receiver goes to IDLE state... I could only change lang after the video is in PLAYING state, otherwise it just broke playback. But how can I start with the 2nd stream?